# How to clone branch with git-p4?

Tags: git-p4

I did:

```
git p4 clone //depot/path/to/project/trunk/@all project
```

to create the `master` branch of `project`. Now I want to clone `//depot/path/to/project/release` to the `release` branch of `project`. How is that done?

UPDATE: Using `--detect-branches` doesn't work, either. It reports that it's updating two branches (when there are really three branches) but `git branch` reports only master exists.

Answer (score 11):

Here are my setup notes from when I was using git-p4. It might be helpful:

- Download the [p4 linux client](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/downloads/download/P4linux26x86_64essentials.html). Store the file in `~/bin` or `/usr/local/bin` and `chmod +x`
- Setup git-p4 as root

  ```
  chmod 755 /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/fast-import/git-p4
  ln -s /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/fast-import/git-p4 /usr/local/bin
  ```
- Define Git globals for git-p4

  ```
  git config --global alias.p4 '!git-p4'
  git config --global git-p4.detectRenames true
  git config --global git-p4.detectCopies true
  ```
- Set defines for direct 'p4' usage

  ```
  export P4PORT=SERVER_NAME:PORT_NUMBER
  ```
- Set login credentials

  ```
  export P4USER=USER_NAME
  export P4PASSWD=PASSWORD
  ```
- Select Perforce branches using P4 'client'

  Run the 'p4 client' command, and add only the paths/branches you are
  interested in. If you want to name the client work space you can add an
  optional CLIENT_NAME argument to the end of the command. This will allow you
  to use different client definitions on the same machine.

  ```
  $ p4 client [CLIENT_NAME]

  View:
  //depot/main... //CLIENT_NAME/main...
  //depot/patch... //CLIENT_NAME/patch...
  //depot/dev... //CLIENT_NAME/dev...
  ```
- Clone the repository

  - Simple import

    ```
    git p4 clone --use-client-spec --detect-branches //depot@all GIT_DIR
    ```
  - Advanced import

    ```
    git init PROJ; cd PROJ/
    git config git-p4.branchList main:patch
    git config --add git-p4.branchList main:dev
    git p4 clone --use-client-spec //depot@all .
    ```
- Submit Changes Back to Perforce

  In order to submit changes to Perforce, it requires a client workspace,
  separate from the git working tree. It is recommend that the workspace is on
  the same file system your Perforce git working directory.

  Additionally, a reference to the workspace path is stored on the Perforce
  server, and will be used during the `p4 submit` command.

  The first step is to create the local client workspace. `CLIENT_NAME` is
  an optional argument. If you do not define it, p4 will use your host name.

  ```
  p4 client [CLIENT_NAME]
  ```

  You will be moved to a file editor before completing the p4 command. This
  lets you change any of the client settings before they are sent to the
  server. You must change the `Root` value to a new directory outside of your
  git tree (e.g.  ../p4-working) Also, verify the `Owner` and `Client`
  values before exiting.  These values are taking from your environment, and
  can not be changed in the editor.

  ```
  p4 clients | grep USERNAME
  ```

  If you did not use the default client name, it must be defined in your local
  git config:

  ```
  git config git-p4.client CLIENT_NAME
  ```

  When you are ready to push your code changes, use the commands:

  ```
  git p4 rebase
  git p4 submit
  ```

  You can remove clients from the sever when no longer in use:

  ```
  p4 client -d CLIENT_NAME
  ```

Comment: You're missing --add in the second `git config --add git-p4.branchList main:dev`

Answer (score 1):

With Git 2.30 (Q1 2021), "[`git`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ca8870d7c198b658a0e3004e27d1c36305702f7f/Documentation/git-.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-))</sup> p4" now honors `init.defaultBranch` configuration.

That could be an alternative solution to  `detect-branches` or `--branch`:

See [commit 1b09d19](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1b09d1917f376d52e191102509d08303f8d26388) (08 Nov 2020) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit ca8870d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ca8870d7c198b658a0e3004e27d1c36305702f7f), 11 Nov 2020)</sup>

> ### [`p4`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1b09d1917f376d52e191102509d08303f8d26388): respect `init.defaultBranch`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>

> In `git p4 clone`, we hard-code the branch name `master` instead of looking what the *actual* initial branch name is.
> Let's fix that.

Furthermore:

With Git 2.37 (Q3 2022), `git p4 sync --branch` is more complete:

See [commit 17f273f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/17f273ffbad8724278e0fa4da592a7ec7c6abc83) (04 Apr 2022) by [Tao Klerks (`TaoK`)](https://github.com/TaoK).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit af3a320](https://github.com/git/git/commit/af3a3205d14561e1683ca86b894888f9f1fc0176), 20 May 2022)</sup>

> ### [`git-p4`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/17f273ffbad8724278e0fa4da592a7ec7c6abc83): support explicit sync of arbitrary existing `git-p4` refs
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Tao Klerks</sup>

> With the `--branch` argument of the sync subcommand, `git-p4` enables you to import a perforce branch/path to an arbitrary Git ref, using a full ref path, or to `refs/remotes/p4/*` or `refs/heads/p4/*`, depending on `--import-local`, using a short ref name.
>
> However, when you later want to explicitly sync such a given ref to pick up subsequent `p4` changes, it only works if the ref was placed in the `p4` path *and* has only one path component (no "/").
>
> This limitation results from a bad assumption in the existing-branch sync logic, and also means you cannot individually sync branches detected by `--detect-branches`, as these also get a "`/`" in their names.
>
> Fix `git p4 sync --branch`, when called with an existing ref, so that it works correctly regardless of whether the ref is in the `p4` path or not, and (in the case of refs in the `p4` path) regardless of whether it has a "`/`" in its short name or not.

Answer (score 0):

I believe "detect branches" relies on you having a branch mapping with the same name as the branch path in your depot. If that is not the case, you probably need to use the [suggested method](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-p4.html#_branch_detection) of defining the `git-p4.branchList` config value in an empty git repo before running the git-p4 clone command.

Comment: Ah, this makes sense. I was wondering how the branch detection 'magic' worked. I'll give this a try. Thanks.

Comment: This is still not working for me. I suspect merges have gone in both directions on at least some of our branches and it's throwing a wrench into the works of git-p4.

Comment: It's worked for me in the past on a very large repo, with someone of most confusing branches/merging I've ever seen. Since the git-p4 is written in python, its actually not that hard to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Horribly late answer, but there's so little documentation on git-p4 that I hope it's still useful.

I also struggled to add branches to an existing repository, and never got the `detect-branches` magic to work with branch mappings.

I had a little more success doing it in stages manually, explicitly telling git-p4 which path to import and using the `--branch` option.  I believe I also manually created the `release` branch in the existing repository before running that.

For this question, that would be `git p4 sync //depot/path/to/project/release --branch=release`

I believe this would work using `clone` too, as clone is mostly just sync behind the scenes in the git-p4 code, but once you already have a repository, I think `sync` would be safer.